# How to deploy meanjs to heroku

Tags: heroku, meanjs

I have tried deploying my meanjs on heroku.

- I forked this https://github.com/meanjs/mean

1.) Login to heroku 
2.) Deploy and connect github repositor

- enabled automatic deploy CI
- Click on Manual Deploy

On the build log it says "Bulid succeded"

My question is.
Why am I getting this application error?
When all I did was forked the repository and deployed it on heroku?

https://serkolgame.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add a mongoDB to your app? Without it, the startup process is likely to fail.

Here are some options:

- If you are using the default dev environment - then just add the mongodb connection string in development.js and restart the server
- If you are using the prod environment - then you can use environment variables uri: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL or process.env.MONGOLAB_URI

This is assuming you have a mongoDB sandbox setup somewhere, if you don't, you'll first need a mongodb sandbox (get one from Heroku, Compose.io, or MongoLab).